# Exact differential equation with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $M(x,y) +N(x,y) \frac{dy}{dx}=0$ (1)

And $- \frac{\frac{\delta}{\delta y}M - \frac{\delta}{\delta x}N}{xM - yN}=h(xy)$

Show that, for some smooth real function h, $e^{\int h(xy)d(xy)}=\mu (x,y)$ is an integrating factor for (1).
Does anyone know how to tackle a problem like this one?

Edit: can we say $\mu (x,y) = \mu(xy)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\mu(x,y)$ is an integrating factor if and only if it can be multiplied to the differential equation on both sides and change it to an exact equation. If the differential equation is already exact, there is no need for an integrating factor.... Although I've answered your question, I'd also like to add that you need to ensure that no solutions were lost as a result of multiplying the original differential equation by the integrating factor (i.e, check for solutions to $\mu(x,y) = 0$.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, in this specific case can we say $\mu (x,y) = \mu(xy)$ given h is a function of xy?

Comment: That's correct. This can easily be seen by using a new variable, say $v$, such that $v = xy$.